# Fatal error : call to undefined method only in localhost

Tags: php

Given below is my class

```
class Techsoft
{
    private $dbh;


 //Database Connection
   public function __construct($DB_con)
     {
         $this->dbh = $DB_con;
     }
  //function to select values from a table
public function select_rows($table,$fieldlist,$condition,$data)
{       
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT $fieldlist FROM $table $condition");
$stmt->execute($data);
return $stmt;
}//end function
//select rooms
public function Room($listingid,$room_id){
    $cond_bathroom = "WHERE LISTINGID=? ORDER BY ROOM_ID ASC";
    $data_bathroom= array($listingid);
    $select_room=$this->select_rows(TABLEPREFIX.'rooms','*',$cond_bathroom,$data_bathroom); 
    while($arr_cat=$select_room->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($room_id == $arr_cat['ROOM_ID']){
         $sel_cnt='selected'; 
         }else{
             $sel_cnt ='';
             }

    echo '<option value='.$arr_cat['ROOM_ID'].' '.$sel_cnt.'>'.$arr_cat['ROOM_NAME'].'</option>';       
    }

    }//end function 
   }
```

When I call this function `$objA->Room($listing,'');` it was quite fine. But now its showing an error like this `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Techsoft::Room()`. but the same seems to be fine in the sever.
I have tried all this by passing and skipping parameters `$objA->Room($listing,$roomid);` `$objA->Room('','');`. It should work actually but im getting fatal error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error is your version PHP you use.
you can use static class call function with Techsoft::Room() from php version >= 5.5

You can check this in your localhost

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add 'where' for this query.

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT $fieldlist FROM $table where $condition");
```

Comment: No check `$cond_bathroom` !! OP mention WHERE there